# Which DLL can I find BIO_Write

Tags: c++, openssl

I do come across this BIO_Read, BIO_Write For openSSL, I wanted to ask, can it be found inside of chrome.dll or secure32.dll.

Just wanted to know. I couldn't find any useful information about it.

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Comment: found out it was libeay32.dll , but when i revered chrome.dll to check for libeay32.dll, i found nothing. especially for latest chrome

Answer (score 1):

> I do come across this BIO_Read, BIO_Write For openSSL, I wanted to ask, can it be found inside of chrome.dll or secure32.dll.

Its not in third party libraries, like `chrome.dll` or `secure32.dll`. It is in OpenSSL's *Crypto* library (`libcrypto.a` and `libcrypto.so`):

```
$ grep -IR BIO_write * | grep 'int ' | grep -v pod
crypto/bio/bio_lib.c:int BIO_write(BIO *b, const void *data, int dlen)
crypto/bio/bio_lib.c:int BIO_write_ex(BIO *b, const void *data, size_t dlen, size_t *written)
include/openssl/bio.h:int BIO_write(BIO *b, const void *data, int dlen);
include/openssl/bio.h:int BIO_write_ex(BIO *b, const void *data, size_t dlen, size_t *written);
...
```

I believe the Windows equivalent to the Unix library is `libeay32.dll`.

---

> Just wanted to know. I couldn't find any useful information about it.

Check the man pages at [OpenSSL man pages](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manpages.html). Pick a version, like 1.0.2, and then drill into [the crypto library](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/).

Comment: only i dont get to see libeay32.dll when i revered chrome.dll and checked the Executable Modules.

Comment: @James - Maybe its loaded with a call to `LoadLibrary` or `LoadPackagedLibrary`.

Comment: LoadLibraryA("libeay32.dll") you mean ?